# Does vertica supports changing type from int to boolean?

Tags: vertica

I am using vertica 7.1 version. Want to change column type from integer to boolean. But unable to do it . Is it possible with type cast while alter ? If yes how ?

```
testdb=> create table fruits (id int, name varchar(5));
CREATE TABLE

testdb=> insert into fruits values (1,'apple');
 OUTPUT 
--------
      1
(1 row)

testdb=> insert into fruits values (1,'orang');
 OUTPUT 
--------
      1
(1 row)
```

```
testdb=> alter table fruits alter column id set data type  boolean;
ROLLBACK 2377:  Cannot convert column "id" from "int" to type "boolean"

testdb=> alter table fruits alter column id set data type  boolean id::boolean;
ERROR 4856:  Syntax error at or near "id" at character 59
LINE 1: ...ble fruits alter column id set data type  boolean id::boolea...
```

Comment: Why not just start using the boolean type for your insertions?

Comment: While the query gets fired joins with other table of same type, in this case one of the table has column int type and other has column boolean type,  leading to query failure. That is why i wanted to change the column type.

Answer (score 0):

Vertica does not support data type changes requiring storage reorganisation. In the Administrator's Guide you can find the list of supported data type changes:

- Binary types—expansion and contraction but cannot convert between BINARY and VARBINARY types.
- Character types—all conversions allowed, even between CHAR and VARCHAR
- Exact numeric types—INTEGER, INT, BIGINT, TINYINT, INT8, SMALLINT, and all NUMERIC values of scale <=18 and precision 0 are interchangeable. For NUMERIC data types, you cannot alter scale, but you can change the precision in the ranges (0-18), (19-37), and so on.

Comment: yeah this i got from this link : https://my.vertica.com/docs/7.1.x/HTML/Content/Authoring/SQLReferenceManual/Statements/ALTERTABLE.htm